# Pull records from previous three months

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to pull back all the rows that have a report date from the previous 3 months. So If I'm running the code in March 2015, I want to pull back data from Dec14, Jan15, Feb 15.

I've tried to use the following but not had much success

```
    Select * from table 
where DATEPART(month, ReportDate) between Month(DATEADD(month, -1,GETDATE())) and Month(DATEADD(month, -3,GETDATE()))
```

Comment: you need to start with the smaller number `Month(DATEADD(month, -3,GETDATE()))` and finish with the larger number `Month(DATEADD(month, -1,GETDATE()))`

Comment: not to mention the missing FROM and WHERE...

Comment: Next time, test your DateAdd functions separately, think about the results and how they would make sense to use in a BETWEEN clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the first day of the current month using:

```
SELECT  DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, '1900001', GETDATE()), '19000101')
```

This basically just gets the number of months between now, and a fixed date, then adds this number of months back to the same fixed date, to get the first of the current month. Then it is just a case of adding this into your query, so your pseudo code is:

```
WHERE ReportDate < [start of this month]
AND ReportDate >= [start of 4 months ago]
```

And your actual code is:

```
WHERE ReportDate < DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, '19000101', GETDATE()), '19000101')
AND ReportDate >= DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, '19000401', GETDATE()), '19000101');
```

Note that I have removed the function from the ReportDate column which will make your predicate [sargable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable)

Here are a couple of good articles on querying date ranges:

- [Bad habits to kick : mis-handling date / range queries](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries)
- [What do BETWEEN and the devil have in common?](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)

Comment: Thanks for this. Will I have to edit any of the code each month then? i.e. change the month numbers?

Comment: No, the code will always give you the previous 3 months, as `GETDATE()` changes, the result of the function will change.

Comment: Great thanks so much. If I wanted to pull just one month back would it be changing the 4 to a 2?

Comment: Exactly. Just change the 4 to a 2.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTableName
WHERE ReportDate
BETWEEN DATEADD(month, -4,GETDATE()) AND 
DATEADD(month, -1,GETDATE())
```

Comment: The first issue with this query is that it won't work from February to March, in March for example you will end up with `WHERE MONTH(ReportDate) BETWEEN 12 AND 2`, which will never return a result. The second issue is that it only covers a two month period, and the third issue is that it does not take into account the year, so will return results from previous years.

Comment: Good points, originally I had something like: `where ReportMonth BETWEEN DATEADD(MONTH, -3, GETDATE())` to take into account the year etc. Then for some reason I changed it..not quite sure what I was thinking.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this,

```
create table Test(id int, TranDate datetime)
insert into Test (id, TranDate) values
(1, '2014-12-12'),
(2, '2014-11-10'),
(3, '2015-04-01'),
(4, '2015-02-02'),
(5, '2015-01-01')
    
declare @FromDate DateTime = dateadd(month, -4, getdate())
declare @ToDate DateTime  = dateadd(month, -1, getdate())

select * from Test where TranDate >= @FromDate and TranDate <= @ToDate
```

[Sql Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/50e5a/5)

Dont use [`BETWEEN`](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common) clause in sql.